# How to use 'Select' import from 'ionic-angular' in ionic4

Tags: angular, import, ionic4

I want to use the import { Select} from 'ionic-angular' to programmatically open the ionic-select component.

Previous threads have used the import, but ionic 4 doesn't detect 'select' in 'ionic-angular' or '@ionic/angular'.

I have tried replacing 'ionic-angular' with '@ionic-angular'

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { PopoverController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ValidEstatesPage } from '../valid-estates/valid-estates.page';
import {Select} from '@ionic/angular';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-otp',
  templateUrl: './otp.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./otp.page.scss'],
})
export class OtpPage implements OnInit {

  SelectOption: boolean;
  value = 0;
  @ViewChild('popSelect') selectPop: Select;
  constructor(private popoverController: PopoverController, p) {
    this.SelectOption = false;
  }
  submitOTP(): void {

    this.SelectOption = true;
  }

   async openPopover(ev: Event) {
    const popover = await this.popoverController.create({
      component: ValidEstatesPage,
      componentProps: {
        custom_id: this.value
      },
      ev: ev
    });
    popover.present();
  }

  resendOTP(): void {

  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

[All ionic components are now prefixed with `Ion`](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#angular-prefixed-ion--components)

So your import should look like:

```ts
import { IonSelect } from '@ionic/angular';

// ...

@ViewChild('popSelect') selectPop: IonSelect;

// ...

this.selectPop.open();
```